# Uniqueness of a Complete Minimal Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $R$ be a complete Riemannian Manifold of dimension $n$, let $S \subseteq R$ be homeomorphic to the sphere of dimension $k < n$, and let $M$ be a minimal surface of $R$ which is homeomorphic to the ball of dimension $k + 1$ and has $S$ as its boundary.  If we allow self-intersections, does this minimal surface extend to some unique complete minimal surface?  If $k = 0$, then $S$ is a pair of points and our $M$ is a geodesic connecting these two points, and this geodesic can be extended past either point in a unique way by moving "straight" past the points, and doing this process indefinitely leads to a unique geodesic which is either topologically a line or a circle (possibly with self-intersections), both of which are complete.  I was wondering if this idea extends for higher dimensions. Perhaps the requirements about the boundary being homeomorphic to a $k$-sphere and the minimal surface being homeomorphic to a $k+1$-ball could be laxed.

Comment: Presumably you're requiring $R$ to be complete? Even with that assumption, minimal surfaces in dimension $\ge 2$ can have singularities which prevent them from being immersed submanifolds.

Comment: I’m okay with a failure to be immersed.  I’m more curious if the way to extend this bounded minimal hypersurface has a unique solution, or if you could end up with multiple different manifolds from extending the original bounded minimal surface.

Comment: Two questions with the same title? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223324/uniqueness-of-complete-minimal-surfaces

Comment: I attempted to retitle the other one to this ones without realizing this question already had this title.  I figured that neither question was popular enough for it to really matter if I swapped the names and slightly edited the original title.  I’ll probably just end up renaming this question if it’s that big of a deal as I’m more concerned with the newer question at the moment.

Comment: @NullSimplex In that case, you'll have to define what you mean by "minimal surface", since there isn't an obvious generalization beyond the immersed case. Also, to my knowledge it's frowned upon to ask essentially the same question multiple times, it would probably be best to merge the two.

Comment: @Kajelad As I understand it the natural generalization of 1-dimensional geodesics (which locally minimize distance) and 2-dimensional minimal surfaces (which locally minimize area) are n-dimensional minimal hypersurfaces (which locally minimize n-dimensional volume).  These manifolds are also characterized by having 0 mean curvature relative to the manifold it is immersed in.  I will consider removing this question due to the complaints.