# Uniqueness of Bounded Minimal Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Say you have a complete Riemann manifold $R$ and a complete minimal hypersurface $M$ of dimension $n$ embedded in $R$.  Say we remove all but but a patch $P$ from $M$ where $P$ is topologically $B^n$.  Is $M$ the unique manifold that results from extending $P$?

It seems to me that in the case of $n = 1$, the statement is true.  If you have a complete geodesic embedded in some complete Riemann manifold and you remove all but a small line segment of that geodesic, then extending that line segment in both directions gets you the original geodesic.  I was wondering if this idea carries over to higher dimensions.

Comment: Two questions with the same title? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134845/uniqueness-of-a-complete-minimal-surfaces

Comment: I didn’t see what the issue was since neither was garnering much attention and they are almost asking the same thing in a different way.  But it has been changed back to it’s original title.